# Eslint error in postcss.config at vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, postcss

I have started a new vue-cli project with

```
vue create -n tailwind-demo

? Please pick a preset: Manually select features
? Check the features needed for your project: Babel, TS, PWA, Vuex, Linter
? Use class-style component syntax? Yes
? Use Babel alongside TypeScript (required for modern mode, auto-detected polyfills, transpiling JSX)? Yes
? Pick a linter / formatter config: Prettier
? Pick additional lint features: Lint on save, Lint and fix on commit
? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, ESLint, etc.? In dedicated config files
```

I have also add the following `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-preset-env")({ stage: 0 }),
    require("tailwindcss")(),
    require("autoprefixer")()
  ]
};
```

When i run the yarn lint command it got the follow errors

```
error: Require statement not part of import statement (@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires) at postcss.config.js:3:5:
error: Require statement not part of import statement (@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires) at postcss.config.js:4:5:
error: Require statement not part of import statement (@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires) at postcss.config.js:5:5:
```

How can i import the plugins or how should i configure the eslint in Vue CLI for the postcss.config.js?

I have tried something like

```
import tailwindCss from "tailwindcss";
```

But i got a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` while building.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with the following `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-preset-env": {
      stage: 0
    },
    tailwindcss: {}
  }
};
```